# AES-IS support and processor architecture in 2010 iMacs

Tags: filevault, encryption, cpu, macos

Which processor architecture was used in mid 2010 27'' iMacs? (iMac11,3 - EMC 2390)

The CPU is an Intel quad-core Core i5 CPU, 2.8 GHz.

I'm trying to find out if it supports the [AES Instruction Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) natively at the hardware level, because it would significantly speed up File Vault encryption.

So far I've found that it could either be [Clarkdale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarkdale_(microprocessor)) or [Lynnfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynnfield_(microprocessor)), but [only the first one](http://ark.intel.com/products/48496/Intel-Core-i5-760-Processor-8M-Cache-2_80-GHz) should come with hardware support for AES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [27" iMac from Mid-2010](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i5-2.8-27-inch-aluminum-mid-2010-specs.html) (i5, 2.8Ghz) had an i5-760 inside.

The model is, in fact, a Lynnfield processor with quad cores.